# Right strategy when using git for multiple extension development

Tags: git, magento, repository

I have got through the git related quesions and I have not been able to make up my mind.

I have many extensions that I have developed and I want to move from svn to git to be able to use better branching and organization.

I develop extensions for Magento where you the parts of the extensions are not located under 1 folder but are spread across the folder structure.

My extensions have files in the following folders:

- /app/code/community/mynamespace
- /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/mynamespace
- /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mynamespace
- /app/etc/modules /skin/frontend/base/default/css/mynamespace
- /skin/frontend/base/default/js/mynamespace

these folders all contain files from other extensions as well.

I want to be able to develop and test the extensions independently. I know I can use this with branch / change or feature which is great.

Although I would like to be able to check them out / extensions which means only those files are pulled which belong to a certain extension.

Can I do the following ?

- put each extension to it's own repository ?
- embed each extension into a super repository which contains the main magento code so that the extensions can be tested either using sub-tree or submodules ?

Would this approach work at all ? 
Is there any other way that I am not aware of ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDITED:

Should I create an EMPTY REPO, then branch the empty repo to as many branches as extension. 
then I should be able to merge back the code to master, and do development on the individual branches. In this case what happens when after adding things to the master I need a new empty branch for a new extension ? Can I create an empty branch and branch that ? Is that even possible ?

thanks guys, I thing I am getting closer to a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your modules are completely unrelated to each other I would create them in their own repositories. For testing purposes, create in it's own independent folder a blank install of whichever version of Magento you wish to develop for. Then create symlinks to the 5 folders you mention in the appropriate places within this.

For testing development create a project which includes just the contents of that repository, but since development without the main source is confusing, most IDE's allow you to include code from an additional folder, so add in whichever version of Magento you are developing testing for, so that you can easily reference the code base.

Now you should be able to test as you work, distributing the module can be a simple case of git exporting and zipping the contents. You then have a simple zip file like any other distributed Magento module, sans Magento core files.

I've actually just started working on a phing based build tool to make Magento Extension development easier, (which you can find at https://github.com/pocallaghan/mephing), but it's in it's early stages and currently lacks any documentation.

Comment: Thanks for this, Phing looks like ANT from the syntax. it looks like a good idea you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Yer, phing was built based on the ANT syntax. At our office, we've been looking at adopting a continuous integration cycle for some work and decided to phing to help with this. I've been playing around for awhile on the best development cycle for extensions, and phing seemed like a useful bases for a set of tools.

Comment: Great, do you write a blog or something where I can see your development cycle, especially how the CI works with it ? I am trying to establish the same, and wonder if you are happy to share your ideas on it.

Comment: Not currently. I have plans to start blogging, it's just a matter of finding time. I'll link the blog on github if I even find the time :)

Answer (score 1):

If each extension is independent of the other, you could probably maintain each in a separate branch (instead of it's own repository as you suggest).

e.g. If you developed 3 extensions, you would have four development branches in your git tree:

```
master
extn1
extn2
extn3
```

Everytime the magento code changes, you pull it into master and then rebase your three development branches on top of the latest changes in master.

And if you want to test with them all, just create a new test branch and merge master, extn1, extn2 and extn3 into it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, this seems like an easy enough solution without the complications of subtrees. Can I keep only the files belong to the extension in the branch ? and still merge it to the master ? As I do not want to keep all the magento related files in each individual branch, would that work ?

Comment: If you rebase every time the master changes, you will LOSE development history and you will never be able to reproduce old versions of your code.  This is exactly the wrong reason to rebase.  You really should be merging instead of rebasing in this situation.

Comment: @Istvano git will not 'waste' any space if that is what you're worried about. Your branch will contain references to common code in master (until you modify it).

Comment: @DietrichEpp Right, the merge vs. rebase debate. If the OP is going to actually submit these extensions to upstream magento, then rebasing is the right way to go. But if these are only going to remain private, then as you suggest, merge is the right strategy (I don't know anything about magento)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty straight forward and I guess NomadCoder presented great way to solve the problem . My suggestion would be to make Development Branch and Release Branch which will help to direct workflow. And since merging branches is easy it will help your work flow transparent. Here a list of git codes you might find handy in your case

[Git Brushup](http://aayushtuladhar.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/git-brushup/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done and is something I do for my extension development. The way I achieved this is using the following steps:

1. Create a repo for each extension I develop
2. Clone 1 repo into my Magento installation
3. Merge the cloned files into Magento and put the .git file in the root of my Magento. I can now pull/push from this extension
4. Next, I rename the .git file in the root of Magento .git%s, where %s is a 2 character string representing the extenion.
5. Next, clone the second extension repo into Magento.
6. Repeat step 3 to 6 untill all extensions are in Magento

After this, I have the following git files in the root of my Magento install:

1. .gitwp
2. .gitbp
3. .gitwps
4. .gitas

Now, I can work all my projects at the same time. If for example, I want to push my changes from the WP project, I can run the following commands:

```
mv .gitwp .git
git push origin master
mv .git .gitwp
```

Using the above system I can easily work on all of my extensions in the same Magento environment, while keeping separate Repository's.

I hope this helps